# Microsoft Mouse Settings do not work after restart until I open preferences

Tags: hardware, mouse, system-settings, driver, microsoft

I seem to have this same problem my work and home Macbook Pro Systems.  Both are running Mavericks.

The Mouse is a [Microsoft Explorer Touch Mouse](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/explorer-touch-mouse) and I have the latest version (8.2) of IntelliPoint for Mac.

I have a few custom settings configured; the top and bottom of the scroll button are set to browse back and forward, and the middle-click is set to "Handled by Mac OS" which causes it to open links in new tabs, etc.

The problem is whenever I restart the system or even sleep and wake up, when I return those settings are no longer working until I open system preferences and open the settings for the microsoft mouse.  The settings do maintain what I set them to -- I never have to reset them -- but they just don't seem to be "turned on" until I manually open the system preferences page for them.

<sub>**The mouse works**, but the **custom buttons do not do the correct thing** until I open system preferences->microsoft mouse. When I open the preferences I do not need to change anything-- I simply open the preferences window and the buttons start doing what I want them to. And The preferences window always shows the correct settings. The continue to work after I close them until the next restart. It's like there's an invisible "on/off" switch that gets activated when I open the settings window</sub>

Any ideas on how I can get these settings to be enabled automatically without needing to do this every time?

Comment: Usually when system does not "save" your settings there is a problem with the "permissions". One is to use the disk utility and repair the permissions. The second one is to reset your ACL's (your account specific permissions).

Comment: @Buscar웃 The settings **are** being saved -- they are not changed.  They simply do not work until I open system settings. I never have to change anything. Also this same exact problem is happening on two different systems -- this leads me to think it's a problem with the mouse software itself and not corrupted permissions.

Comment: Your mouse does not "wake up" on system start ? does it work with non customized settings, or does it work in Safe mode ?

Comment: Hmmm, let me try to explain this better.  The mouse works, but the custom buttons do not do the correct thing until I open system preferences->microsoft mouse.  When I open the preferences I do not need to change anything-- I simply open the preferences window and the buttons start doing what I want them to.  And The preferences window always shows the correct settings. The continue to work after I close them until the next restart.   It's like there's an invisible "on/off" switch that gets activated when I open the settings window.

Comment: @Buscar웃 OK, thanks! I will try that and let you know.  The system log only produced 2 entries when I reproduced that; neither looked helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information provided I would say the mouse settings are not been loaded.

You can add the "MicrosoftMouseHelper" to the log in items area.

That should override the OS X defaults.

The file should be located in your `/Library/PreferencePanes/Microsoft Mouse.PrefPane/Contents/Resources/MicrosoftMouseHelper`

Comment: Thanks, looks like that worked!  You may want to add the full path of /Library/PreferencePanes/Microsoft Mouse.PrefPane/Contents/Resources/MicrosoftMouseHelper